# Animar una vista slideUp y SlideDown en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Como se podría animar por ejemplo un `LinearLayout` que alberga un banner, con animación `SlideUp` para mostrarlo y `SlideDown` para ocultarlo en conjunto `Toggle`.

Quiero realizar un visualizador de banner propio, que detecte cuando se ha ocultado para cargar el siguiente banner de una lista.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
final View banner = findViewById(R.id.banner);

banner.animate()
        .translationY(banner.getHeight())
        .alpha(0.0f)
        .setDuration(650)
        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                //Carga del nuevo banner para volver a mostrar

                banner.animate()
                        .translationY(0)
                        .alpha(1.0f)
                        .setDuration(650);
            }
        });
```

Pero me encuentro que la animación solo se realiza una vez.

Digamos al lanzar la acción, realiza `slide Down` y cuando acaba `slide Up`, la segunda vez que le doy para realizar la acción no hace `slide` sino le aplica `fadeOut` y `fadeIn`, es como si pasase completamente de `.translationY(banner.getHeight())`

¿Cómo se puede solventar que la animación se pueda repetir la veces que sea necesaria?
La finalidad es que este dentro de un `Runable` que cada N segundos se aplique la acción de cargar el banner.

Comment: no entiendo muy bien que es lo que hace o lo que necesitas que haga, quizá si me explicas un poco mas detallado o con algún ejemplo, pueda ayudarte :P

Comment: Buenas @Bourne ya lo solucione, no me he recordado en postear la solución, lo que quería es animar un imageview slidedown -> cargar nueva imagen ->slideup todo automaticamente

Comment: @Bourne he modificado la pregunta, para ver si queda más claro lo que quiero, de momento lo solvento de esa manera, pero no ser si es la optima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solventando poner un `AnimatorListenerAdapter` a la segunda animación.

```
final View banner = findViewById(R.id.banner);

banner.animate()
        .translationY(banner.getHeight())
        .alpha(0.0f)
        .setDuration(650)
        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                //Carga del nuevo banner para volver a mostrar

                banner.animate()
                        .translationY(0)
                        .alpha(1.0f)
                        .setDuration(650);
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        }
            }
        });
```